# Require 0 or many keys in object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a function that accepts an object with specific keys, but I'd like for my developers to also be able to leave these keys undefined so I can throw an error in case that specific key is used.

However I can't figure out how to not require all keys. This is my code:

```
type Keys = "One" | "Two" | "Three"

export const getConfig = (
  key: Keys,
  config: {
    [key in Keys]: AnotherType;
  }
) => {
  if (!config[key]) {
    throw new Error(`Could not find config.`);
  }

  return config[key];
};
```

I'd like the function to be used like this:

```
getConfig('One', {
    One: {},
    Three: {}
}
```

But obviously this gives me the following error:

```
Property 'Two' is missing in type
```

I've tried any combination of undefined but haven't been able to get it to work.

Current workaround looks like this:

```
getConfig('One', {
    One: {},
    Two: null as unknown as any,
    Three: {}
}
```

But it's obviously not great DX...

How can I get this working?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `{ [key in Keys]?: AnotherType }` (or alternatively `Partial<{ [key in Keys]: AnotherType }>`?)

Comment: The second one worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is lots of solution, depends on how you will use the function.

one is define the `config` to `Record<string, AnotherType>` because you will check the exists of the key inside the function.

```
export const getConfig = (key: Keys, config: Record<string, AnotherType>) => {
    // ...
};
```

---

you may want to restrict the key of `config` (the original question in the post), you can combined `Partial` and `Record` to do this:

```
export const getConfig = (key: Keys, config: Partial<Record<Keys, AnotherType>>) => {
    // ...
};
```

however, this turns the return type to `AnotherType|undefined` because `Partial`

---

The last one is use generic to static check and ensure the `key` exist in the `config` object, this solution skipped the runtime check (`throw ...`)

```
export const getConfig = <T extends Keys, Config extends Record<T, AnotherType>>(key: T, config: Config) => {
    return config[key] // Config[T] (AnotherType)
};
```

and another kind of generic function with only one type parameter:

```
export const getConfig = <Config extends Partial<Record<Keys, AnotherType>>>(key: keyof Config, config: Config) => {
    return config[key]
};
```

Comment: Combining partial and record was the solution I needed, thank you!